# size of Journal files are increasing not getting cleaned up

Tags: mongodb

Using mongodb version 3.4.1.

Size of journal file are not getting cleaned up after upgrade patch of windows(2012 R2)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXXRI.png) where mongodb is running. Nothing is showing in logs.

I have attached snap of journal files.

Journal files are increasing rapidly though do not having the Space in data directory can we delete the journal files??.

Comment: You shouldn't delete journal files while the running MongoDB instance is potentially using or referencing them. If there are excessive journal files you could be able to safely clearly these by restarting your MongoDB server (not ideal, but better than introducing consistency problems). Can you edit your question to include a list of some of the journal files and dates? Also, what is the upgrade patch you just applied -- is that upgrading Windows or upgrading MongoDB and what were you upgrading from/to?

Comment: I strongly recommend upgrading to the latest MongoDB 3.4.x production release (currently 3.4.20) as there have been many bug fixes & improvements since 3.4.1 was released in Dec, 2016 (see: [release notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4/)). I'm not certain if that will fix your issue, but this does not include any backward-breaking changes and is a better starting point for troubleshooting.

Comment: Journal files are getting increase since 1 month with the upgradation of windows patch which is windows 2012 R2 server,